# How UpdateModel method works in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to know the working of UpdateModel() method. I just know about it is for update the current model data. but how it works exactly ? Because while I am using the UpdateModel() in edit controller method, there is functionality of file uploads. I am keeping the path of uploaded file in my db. but after executes the UpdateModel method value of path is replaces with "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper" . why this should happens :
Code:

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Files["TDSCertificatePath"].FileName))
                {
                    TrustTrusteeMapping objTrustTrusteeMapping = trust_trustee_mapping_management.GetTrustTrusteeMappingById(objTDSDetail.TrustTrusteeMappingId);
                    string TrustTrusteeMappingName = objTrustTrusteeMapping.Trust.TrustName + "_" + objTrustTrusteeMapping.TrusteeMaster.FullName;
                    HttpPostedFileBase fileToUpload = Request.Files["TDSCertificatePath"];
                    objTDSDetail.TDSCertificatePath = CommonFunctions.UploadFile("TDSCertificatePath", "Content\\TDSCertificate\\", TrustTrusteeMappingName, fileToUpload);
                    fileToUpload = null;
                    objTrustTrusteeMapping = null;
                }

                UpdateModel(objTDSDetail);//After executes this the value of objTDSDetail.TDSCertificatePath changes as I said before.
```

Comment: Why don't you grab the MVC source, and debug for yourself? Or if you can't be bothered, you can look at it here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/23011?projectName=aspnet#266451

Comment: excuse me !i tried that , but how UpdateModel() works is not going  (Showing)internal method execution. I want that to see. want to understand the way it works.

Comment: That's because `UpdateModel`, in the end, uses an interface and not a concrete class - try looking at the `DefaultModelBinder.cs` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you bothering with this method. Using a view model passed as action argument is so much easier:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int TrustTrusteeMappingId { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase TDSCertificatePath { get; set; }
}
```

And in your action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    // use the model here whose properties are bound from the POST request
    if (model.TDSCertificatePath.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // a TDSCertificatePath was provided => handle it here
    }
    return RedirectToAction("success");
}
```